# Observable that buffers items when no subscribers, then emits them and clears the buffer when it is subscribed to?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I want an observable that:

1. Can emit items on demand and never really completes (a hot observable?)
2. Is aware of when it has subscribers or not
3. If no subscribers, it will buffer items that I tell it to emit
4. When subscribed, it will emit the buffered items in order, then clear the buffer, and then continue to allow me to emit more items
5. When unsubscribed (subscriber is disposed?), it will go back to buffering.

Also:

1. There is only expected to be one subscriber at a time
2. It does not need to be thread safe

Here's sort of a pseudocode of what I am thinking -- I don't have the necessary callbacks though to do this the right way.  Also it would be nice if I could wrap it all up in an Observable or Subject.

```
class RxEventSender {
    private val publishSubject = PublishSubject.create<Action>()

    val observable: Observable<Action> = publishSubject

    private val bufferedActions = arrayListOf<Action>()

    private var hasSubscribers = false

    fun send(action: Action) {
        if (hasSubscribers) {
            publishSubject.onNext(action)
        } else {
            bufferedActions.add(action)
        }
    }

    //Subject was subscribed to -- not a real callback
    fun onSubscribed() {
        hasSubscribers = true
        bufferedActions.forEach {action ->
            publishSubject.onNext(action)
        }
        bufferedActions.clear()
    }

    //Subject was unsubscribed -- not a real callback
    fun onUnsubscribed() {
        hasSubscribers = false
    }
}
```

Comment: this is interesting and I spent some time trying to figure it out. im not so sure how you can get some type of unsubscribe callback. another idea i had were applying backpressure when there are no subscribers

Comment: The only solution that comes close that i've seen is this: https://github.com/dmdevgo/RxPM/blob/b028ba687e6580493c106d2d8a63d408ea20f77e/rxpm/src/main/kotlin/me/dmdev/rxpm/PmExtensions.kt#L76-L105

Comment: @EpicPandaForce very interesting solution, thanks for sharing

Comment: Can you mention also that you only have one subscriber at a time in your criteria? That makes things clearer. Oh and also that you only require a synchronous solution.

Comment: @DaveMoten done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time, I think this works well enough for my needs.  It's not wrapped up nicely in a Subject or Observable but all I needed was to emit items and subscribe.

```
class RxEventSender<T> {
    private val bufferedEvents = arrayListOf<T>()

    private val publishSubject = PublishSubject.create<T>()

    val observable: Observable<T> = publishSubject
            .mergeWith(Observable.fromIterable(bufferedEvents))
            .doOnDispose {
                bufferedEvents.clear()
            }

    fun send(event: T) {
        if (publishSubject.hasObservers()) {
            publishSubject.onNext(event)
        } else {
            bufferedEvents.add(event)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think your solution makes sense. one thing i would be weary of here is thread safety as it is prone to a few different race conditions as is (and I am assuming different threads will access this if it used with RxJava)

Comment: @WilliamReed you are correct, it is not thread safe.   In my case I know I will only have one subscriber at a time, so it works, but it's not a very robust solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`ReplaySubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/ReplaySubject.html). It has unbounded and bounded versions if you get worried about the buffer getting too big.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  An unbounded `ReplaySubject` gets me 90% of the way there, but after it is subscribed to, and after it has re-emitted all of its buffered items, I want to clear the buffer so it won't re-emit those items again on the next subscription.  Sorry if my question was not clear, I just edited it to make that clear.   Also I described this in the pseudocode above.